# Save a editable Grid View on a single save button ASP.NET 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an editable gridview. The rows are editable. I can save each row by clicking corresponding save button for each row.
But the problem is I can not have save button/Link for each row. there will be a single "save" button below the grid. After changing values on the grid , by clicking on save all the changed rows will be updated in DB.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this tutorial: [GridView Bulk Editing](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattdotson/archive/2005/11/09/real-world-gridview-bulk-editing.aspx)